# How to create a method that takes undefined number of arguments in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to figure out how to create a method in Objective-C that takes undefined number of arguments. Something similar to this java:

```
public void foo(String... args) {
    for (String arg : args) {
      // do smth with arg.
     }
}
```

Thank you in advance.